# latitude long. pass through Geopoint() ,problem in number format

Tags: android

I have done xml parsing and store result as latitude and longitude in an StringArray and using for loop I store result of lat and longitude in a string named "lat" and "longi" I want to pass these points through GeoPoint() for showing in a map,now the problem is now that i have 43 items in array: "sitesList.getLatitude().size()" when i use in our for loop it force close it is showing only 20 items show when i hard coated it then it is showing all lat long in map so now my qus is how to show all 43 position in mymap???

```
  **if i use this then force close and gives number format exceptions...**
  ****// for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getLatitude().size(); i++)****
```

and when i take max size 20 then no  problem occur why???

```
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
     name = sitesList.getLatitude().get(i);
     name1 = sitesList.getLongitude().get(i);
     Log.i("array_spinner" + i, name);
     Log.i("longitiitude"+i,name1);
     point = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(name) * 1E6),
                (int) (Double.parseDouble(name1) * 1E6));
                 OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "Tomorrow ", 
                 "(M gives Bond his mission in Daimler car)");
                 itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a data in your `sitesList` contains null values (excatly at position 20) or it contains values, that can'be parsed as `Double`.

In first case you are getting `NullPointerException`, and in the second one - `NumberFormatException`.

**P.S.** I have seen this bug before... exactly here: [Show marker on google map position obtained from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963165/show-marker-on-google-map-position-obtained-from-xml/5965281#5965281)